# Use Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECDsaCng) without a Key Storage Provider (KSP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cryptography

**The short version:** `CngKey.Import` throws an exception, even though `new ECDsaCng()` doesn't.

(EDIT: More narrowed-down question: [CngKey.Import(...); succeeds on PC but fails on Web host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062583/cngkey-import-succeeds-on-pc-but-fails-on-web-host) .)

**The long version:**

In some scenarios there are permission restrictions and `CngKey.Import` (which is used to "load" the `CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob` into the `ECDsaCng`) throws a `CryptographicException`.

On the other hand the following does work:

```
ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng();
```

So I assume the problem lies in the attempt to import the key into the KSP.

So far I haven't found a way to transform the `EccPrivateBlob` into an `ECDsaCng`, not by the `CngKey.Create` method, nor by the `CngKey.Open` method, or any other way.

So how can it be done (without the KSP)?

The error itself:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error
>   occurred. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.OpenStorageProvider(String
>   providerName) at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[]
>   keyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider) at ...

Comment: That exception probably has a cause, and the cause is probably a better description of the actual problem...

Comment: @owlstead See my subsequent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062583/cngkey-import-succeeds-on-pc-but-fails-on-web-host .

Comment: Is this question still valid?

Comment: @owlstead Yes. It has more information about the problem. (Since I _don't_ yet know what the actual problem is - I don't know what might be relevant to the question.)