# CngKey.Import(...); succeeds on PC but fails on Web host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cryptography

The following line succeeds on my PC but throws an exception on a web host's server:

```
CngKey.Import(EccPrivateBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);    //EccPrivateBlob is a byte[] that works on my PC.
```

The exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error
>   occurred. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.OpenStorageProvider(String
>   providerName) at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[]
>   keyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider) at ...

Is this a security exception? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by enabling `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1` in the Azure portal as mentioned here:

[How can I sign a JWT token on an Azure WebJob without getting a CryptographicException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349954/how-can-i-sign-a-jwt-token-on-an-azure-webjob-without-getting-a-cryptographicexc)